# conda install <package> in a read-only multiuser miniconda setup results in an orphaned package installation

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I admin in a computer science department where hundreds of users with limited filesystem usage quotas are trying to set up conda environments for various computational tasks. So I've been experimenting with setting up multi-user miniconda environments on shared storage in an attempt to get at least the package installs out of users' home directories.

The simple method described here: https://docs.anaconda.com/free/anaconda/install/multi-user/ won't work for us because we have lots of users that can't necessarily be trusted, so a world or even group-writable conda install is not an option. Users could just cd to the miniconda directory and wreak havoc.

The ideal I was aiming for was to set up a number of frequently implemented environments for using things like numpy and pytorch in **/mnt/opt/miniconda/envs**, which users could then activate by (for example)

```
source /mnt/opt/miniconda/bin/activate pytorch
```

This works, but users are unable to install supplemental packages because **/mnt/opt/miniconda/envs/pytorch** is read-only.  What I thought might be possible is that these supplemental packages would be installed in **/home/$USER/.conda/pkgs** and associated with the environment for that user only, but this doesn't seem work. However, in testing things, I ran into a rather strange anomaly.  If I run

```
source /mnt/opt/miniconda/bin/activate numpy
conda install scipy
```

the install fails with what amount to a write permission error.  If, however, I set this environment variable in .bashrc first:

```
export CONDA_PKGS_DIRS="/home/$USER/.conda/pkgs"
```

and then repeat:

```
source /mnt/opt/miniconda/bin/activate numpy
conda install scipy
```

the packages get installed in the correct directory:

```
(numpy) pgoetz@texas-tea pkgs$ pwd
/home/pgoetz/.conda/pkgs
(numpy) pgoetz@texas-tea pkgs$ ls
cache scipy-1.11.1-py311h08b1b3b_0
libgfortran5-11.2.0-h1234567_1 scipy-1.11.1-py311h08b1b3b_0.conda
libgfortran5-11.2.0-h1234567_1.conda urls
libgfortran-ng-11.2.0-h00389a5_1 urls.txt
libgfortran-ng-11.2.0-h00389a5_1.conda
```

but they're not accessible in the environment:

```
(numpy) pgoetz@texas-tea pkgs$ python
Python 3.11.5 (main, Sep 11 2023, 13:54:46) [GCC 11.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
>>>
```

So these are ... orphaned conda packages? Does anyone know what's going on here, or is this just an unanticipated edge case?

Comment: If the package cache is writable but the target environment isn't, then I'd expect that the package will download and unpack, but the installation will fail in the LINK step (i.e., installing it into the environment). Is that what you see?

Comment: Right now this post has multiple questions. The part about orphaned packages is well-defined; the question about how to share environments while still allowing user-customization skews toward recommendation and is more in SysAdmin space. I'd suggest this question be reworked to only focus on the former, whereas the latter should be asked elsewhere (e.g,. https://conda.discourse.group), where discussion with other SysAdmins can happen.

Comment: I think you're probably right in your first comment, and good suggestion on the second.  Let me take care of that.

Comment: I think your comment above could likely be marked as a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like expected behavior. Conda carries out package installation in two phases<sup>**1**</sup>:

- FETCH - packages are downloaded into a cache and unpacked
- LINK - cached packages are copied and/or linked to the target environment

If a package cache is writeable - which the user one, `~/.conda/pkgs`, always should be - then the FETCH stage should execute without a hitch. However, if the target environment is read-only, then the LINK phase could fail. Since cached packages are considered immutable, there is no reason to cleanup anything from the successful FETCH, despite the LINK phase failing.

A `conda clean -tp` should remove the "*orphaned*" packages. However, be aware that if softlinks/symlinks are being used, the `-p, --packages` part could break environments (the `-t, --tarballs` flag is safe).

---

<sub>**[1]:** There can also be an UNLINK phase between these if any packages get upgraded or removed in the transaction. If the target environment is read-only, UNLINK will fail in the same fashion as LINK.</sub>